# How to repeat centered text in a sideway environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rotating, multido

Some text can be repeated, for example, by using `\multido` of the package "multido" and text can be rotated by using the `sideways` environment of the package "rotating". Combining both works. But when trying to center the text additionally there is the revealing error message:

```
Somethings's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

I didn't know that lists come into play... Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,multido}
\begin{document}

%using center environment
\begin{sideways}
\multido{\i=0+1}{3}{%
\begin{center}This is some centered text...\end{center}
}
\end{sideways}

%using \centering
\begin{sideways}
\centering 
\multido{\i=0+1}{3}{%
This is some centered text...\\ \bigskip
}
\end{sideways}

\end{document}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You can use a box: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{sideways}
\parbox{\textheight}{\multido{\i=0+1}{3}{\centering This is some centered text... \\}
}
\end{sideways}

\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in this case is with `\addvspace` (hidden in the definitions of `center` and `\centering`) being called outside vmode, as the following simple example demonstrates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sideways}
\addvspace{3em}
This is some centered text...
\end{sideways}

\end{document}
```

This code triggers the "famous" error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \addvspace{3em}
```

To confirm this, a simple conditional test helps:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{rotating} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{sideways} 
\ifvmode a\else b\fi
\end{sideways} 
\end{document}
```

the above code, typesets "b", so we are not in vmode.

This is so, because `sideways` (and also `rotate` and `turn`) use a `\hbox` to collect the material; for example, in rotating.sty one finds:

```
\def\sideways{%
  \Grot@setangle{90}%
  \setbox\z@\color@hbox\ignorespaces}
```

and then

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\color@hbox{\hbox\bgroup}
}
```

You can prevent the problem using, for example, a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{rotating,multido} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{sideways} 
\parbox{\textheight}{%
  \multido{\i=0+1}{3}{\centering This is some centered text... \\}%
 } 
\end{sideways} 
\end{document}
```

[image]